# Multiple computation of datetime from database to C#

Tags: c#, mysql

can someone help me with my payroll system codes. I want a result where i will get the total number of hours of each employee and before proceeding to another employee it will be saved in a table in mysql. the problems im encountering are
 1. it still counts the datetime even if it is null in database.
 2. after changing the timeline it still counts the previous total hours
    the variable does not reset.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhUTQ.png)

```
public int IdFrom;
        public int Idto;
        public int TotalHours;
        public int day;
        public DateTime time1;
        public DateTime time2;
        public string testNull;
        public string date;
        public string testvariable;
        string testdate1;
        string testdate2;
        TimeSpan totaltime;
        TimeSpan ts;
        private void btn_compute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (rb_all.Checked == true)
            {
                cls.Connection();
                cls.connect.Open();
                cls.command = new MySqlCommand("select ID from tbl_attendance order by ID asc limit 1", cls.connect);
                cls.reader = cls.command.ExecuteReader();
                while (cls.reader.Read())
                {
                    IdFrom = cls.reader.GetInt16(0);
                }
                cls.reader.Close();

                cls.Connection();
                cls.connect.Open();
                cls.command = new MySqlCommand("select ID from tbl_attendance order by ID desc limit 1", cls.connect);
                cls.reader = cls.command.ExecuteReader();
                while (cls.reader.Read())
                {
                    Idto = cls.reader.GetInt16(0);
                }
                cls.reader.Close();

                for(int x = IdFrom;x<=Idto;x++)
                {
                    totaltime = TimeSpan.Zero;
                    ts = TimeSpan.Zero;
                    day = 0;
                    TotalHours = 0;
                    testNull = "";
                    date = "";
                    DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(start_date.Text);
                    DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse(end_date.Text);

                    ts = dt2 - dt;
                    day = ts.Days;
                    for (int y = 0; y <= day; y++)
                    {
                        date = dt.AddDays(y).ToString("yyyy")
                            + "-" + dt.AddDays(y).ToString("MM")
                            + "-" + dt.AddDays(y).ToString("dd");
                        cls.Connection();
                        cls.connect.Open();
                        cls.command = new MySqlCommand("select Time_In,Time_Out from tbl_attendance where Date = '" + date + "' and ID = "+x+"", cls.connect);
                        cls.reader = cls.command.ExecuteReader();
                        while (cls.reader.Read())
                        {
                            time1 = DateTime.Parse(cls.reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
                            time2 = DateTime.Parse(cls.reader.GetValue(1).ToString());

                        }
                        cls.reader.Close();
                        MessageBox.Show(time1.ToString());
                        MessageBox.Show(time2.ToString());
                        totaltime = time2 - time1;
                        MessageBox.Show(totaltime.Hours.ToString());
                        if (totaltime.Hours == 0)
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            TotalHours = TotalHours + (int.Parse(totaltime.Hours.ToString()) - 1);

                        }

                    }//total hours computed
                    if (totaltime.Hours == 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(TotalHours.ToString());

                        break;
                    }

                  }//end of for loop for total number of hours 
            }
```

Comment: You should learn better SQL. A select based on ID using SUM() and a GROUP BY will get you all the rows with one select, and you can just loop through those rows once. And why are you using LIMIT 1 to get one row and then looping, when there's  only one row?

Comment: I used the sql codes that has limits only to get the range of id for the FOR loop, 1 ascending that gets the 1st id number and 1 descending that gets the last number in sql. then I used it for the range in for loop

Comment: You're doing two useless SELECTS. Do a SELECT and ORDER BY ID, and you'll get ALL of the IDs in one pass, which you can then loop through (or better yet, JOIN with the first query I suggested). As I said, find a SQL tutorial and learn more about queries - I've given you suggestions on what you should be looking for to study. (And in any case, if you're selecting with a LIMIT 1, you don't need a `while` loop to read that one row.)

Comment: it seems that you're not aware of **sql injection**

Comment: sorry guys im just a beginner, but thanks to your suggestions, i will try to search first for the joins then sql injections.